# 動画の選択とアップロード

Tags: monaca

こんにちは。
Monacaを使い始めての全くの初心者です。

Androidで動画の選択、アップロードを行いたく思っています。

getPicture関数では画像でフィルタリングされるようで第三引数を見ても画像ででの選択しか無理そうな感じがしています。

MonacaでgetPicture関数のように動画ライブラリを開き、選択、アップロード(これはFileTransferでできそうな気が・・)するための具体例があればご教授いただけませんでしょうか。

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
MediaTypeをVIDEOに変更することでうまくいきました。いろいろこれからも試してみたいと思います。